# Unexpected behavior constructing a java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the following file `lines.txt`

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

I'm using a Scanner to parse the contents of this file line by line.
I have the following setup in LinesReader.java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Line {
    Line(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public String content;

    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}

public class LinesReader {
    public static Line buildLine(InputStream is) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            return new Line(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static Line buildLine(Scanner scanner) {
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            return new Line(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Line line = null;
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("lines.txt");
        // buildLine(scanner) works as expected
        while ((line = buildLine(is)) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        System.err.println(lines);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
[Line1]
```

The expected output would be

```
[Line1, Line2, Line3]
```

I understand the Scanner implements AutoCloseable, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) that would only apply for a
*try-with-resources* construct and not here.  Also, when i debug it is says the underlying stream is open. The second call to `scanner.hasNextLine()` unexpectedly fails.

If I construct the scanner once in main() it works as expected.

My java version is 1.8.0_275

In response to a comment by @Sweeper the scanner seems to buffer up more than what is consumed, the documentation sort of contradicts that.

for `hasNextLine()`

> The scanner does not advance past any input.

for `nextLine()`

> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip **if no line separators are present**.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: You are using multiple scanners to read from the same stream. I don't think that's what you should be doing...

Comment: I think I figured out why this happens. The scanner is reading more than you expect. When you first read from it, it reads the whole file (since the whole file is not very big), and stores it in its buffer. After that, the second scanner couldn't read anything from the stream, because everything is read already.

Comment: @Sweeper That might be correct, a 6kb input file shows the same behavior, a 1.5  megabyte file (250000 lines) reads about 200 lines.

Comment: So what you need is a non-buffered reader that can read lines. I don't think the standard library has such a thing. You might want to write your own custom logic using a `InputStreamReader`. But note that since this is not buffered, it might not be very efficient. You might want to rethink the design of your `build(stream)` method.

Comment: It might be good if you close FileInputStream by adding `is.close()`. This is the reason while debugging it says that stream is open.

Comment: I think every commentator should ponder over the 1st comment of @Sweeper. It's so clear that the while-loop runs a NEW scanner per loop

Comment: There are two levels of abstraction here. When it says "The scanner does not advance past any input.", it is saying that at the scanner level, not at the underlying input stream level. The scanner does not advance, _not_: the input stream does not get read. Also, " it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present." does not imply "only characters until the line separator are buffered if line separators are present".

Comment: @Sweeper Indeed, the culprit is that hasNextLine consumes several kilobytes of the stream. Adding a buffer to the reader itself and then mark() / reset() it   after hasNextLine() + nextLine() is an inconvenient but working solution. Your first comment was spot on. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`hasNextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--)

> The scanner does not advance past any input.

is somewhat misleading. It doesn't advance the internal buffer of the scanner, which is obvious, but several kilobytes of the stream is read.

In this case the entire stream is consumed by `hasNextLine()`.

My personal opinion is that this is a defect in the implementation of Scanner. Scanner is designed for convenience and simplicity, not for performance. Wrapping the InputStream in a BufferedInputStream would be sensible and make the usage a a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

A `Scanner` is buffered, and one cannot expect that the underlying `(File)InputStream` is not read further than what is returned by `nextLine`. In fact the underlying FileInputStream could be advanced to the end-of-file. So the first Scanner instance could let the FileInputStream at the end-of-file.

Since java 8, it is easier to use Path, Files, Stream.

```
Path path = Paths.get("lines.txt");
try (Stream<String> in = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
    List<Line> lines = in.map(Line::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    ...
}
```

The above also automatically closes the file, try-with-resources syntax.

The code is smaller with the new classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    ...
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("lines.txt");
    while (true) {
        System.err.println(is.available());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(new Line(scanner.nextLine()));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I got the following.

```
18
0    <---- FileInputStream is not avaliable for the 2nd Scanner
[Line1]
```

But if I move the line

```
    while (true) {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("lines.txt");
        System.err.println(is.available());
        ...
    }
```

the loop keeps printing out `18`.